# Deserializing JSON to a .NET object puts null in each member of my object, why?

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, json.net, deserialization

I am using JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) to deserialize my JSON into a .NET object - here's my JSON string:

```
{
    "SafetyReport": {
        "SafetyData": [{
            "Unsafe": "YES",
            "CategoryName": "Body Mechanics",
            "CategoryData": "Grip / Force",
            "Safe": "NO"
        }, {
            "Unsafe": "YES",
            "CategoryName": "Position of People",
            "CategoryData": "Falling",
            "Safe": "NO"
        }, {
            "Unsafe": "YES",
            "CategoryName": "Position of People",
            "CategoryData": "Other",
            "Safe": "YES"
        }],
        "SafeActsObserved": "APPLE",
        "UnsafeActsObserved": "OK",
        "Date": "11 / 11 / 1988",
        "ObserverName": "Bob",
        "ObserverGroup": "TEST",
        "LocationAreaRegion": "Nowhere",
        "Email": "abc@abc.com"
    }
}
```

Here's my C# code - please note that the jsonData string contains exactly the JSON above, just in a single line.  I've already verified this:

[image]

Once I step past the deserialization, here's what's in my SafetyReport object:

[image]

Finally, here are my class definitions for `SafetyReport` and `SafetyData`:

```
    public class SafetyReport
    {
        IList<SafetyData> SafetyData { get; set; }
        string SafeActsObserved { get; set; }
        string UnsafeActsObserved { get; set; }
        string Date { get; set; }
        string ObserverName { get; set; }
        string ObserverGroup { get; set; }
        string LocationAreaRegion { get; set; }
        string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class SafetyData
    {
        string Unsafe { get; set; }
        string Safe { get; set; }
        string CategoryName { get; set; }
        string CategoryData { get; set; }
    }
```

**QUESTION**: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working, multiple things might have been wrong, here's what I did:

- Added public modifier to every field.
- Removed `Safetyreport` from JSON
- Changed all doublequotes(") to quotes (')

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{

    'SafetyData': [{
        'Unsafe': 'YES',
        'CategoryName': 'Body Mechanics',
        'CategoryData': 'Grip / Force',
        'Safe': 'NO'
    }, {
        'Unsafe': 'YES',
        'CategoryName': 'Position of People',
        'CategoryData': 'Falling',
        'Safe': 'NO'
    }, {
        'Unsafe': 'YES',
        'CategoryName': 'Position of People',
        'CategoryData': 'Other',
        'Safe': 'YES'
    }],
    'SafeActsObserved': 'APPLE',
    'UnsafeActsObserved': 'OK',
    'Date': '11 / 11 / 1988',
    'ObserverName': 'Bob',
    'ObserverGroup': 'TEST',
    'LocationAreaRegion': 'Nowhere',
    'Email': 'abc@abc.com'
        }
    ";
        SafetyReport sr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SafetyReport>(json);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SafetyReport
{
    public IList<SafetyData> SafetyData { get; set; }
    public string SafeActsObserved { get; set; }
    public string UnsafeActsObserved { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string ObserverName { get; set; }
    public string ObserverGroup { get; set; }
    public string LocationAreaRegion { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class SafetyData
{
    public string Unsafe { get; set; }
    public string Safe { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't help.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What if you try another type for instead of `IList<SafetyData>`? maybe IEnumerable<SafetyData> or List<SafetyData>?

Comment: IList implements IEnumerable so I wouldn't imagine that would be an issue.. let me check.

Comment: I created a project and got it working, see the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is the first field of the JSON, you haven't to set witch class you will deserialize, you have to set the attribute names to identify them. Try with this json.

```
{
    "SafetyData": [{
        "Unsafe": "YES",
        "CategoryName": "Body Mechanics",
        "CategoryData": "Grip / Force",
        "Safe": "NO"
    }, {
        "Unsafe": "YES",
        "CategoryName": "Position of People",
        "CategoryData": "Falling",
        "Safe": "NO"
    }, {
        "Unsafe": "YES",
        "CategoryName": "Position of People",
        "CategoryData": "Other",
        "Safe": "YES"
    }],
    "SafeActsObserved": "APPLE",
    "UnsafeActsObserved": "OK",
    "Date": "11 / 11 / 1988",
    "ObserverName": "Bob",
    "ObserverGroup": "TEST",
    "LocationAreaRegion": "Nowhere",
    "Email": "abc@abc.com"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, the idea I had was I thought I had to match up the class names to the JSON - so, for example, I have a SafetyReport object, which will contain multiple SafetyData records, as well as other members.  So, that's why I had "SafetyReport" at the top level of my JSON to indicate that this is a SafetyReport object.

Comment: And I actually tried this in the beginning, but still no luck.

Comment: One of the problems was the first field.  I removed that, and added public access modifiers to each member of my class and that resolved it.